# Unable to correctly swipe GridView XAML

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've created a GridView with a width of 1800, with several GridViewItems inside it which fills up more than the screen realestate, so I have to swipe to see more content. However, when I swipe horizontally, I can see the content which is not visible before swiping, but once I remove my finger/stop swiping, the GridView automatically slides back to the content on the very left. For some reason, the methods which I've usually used, won't work in this particular project. At the moment, the GridView contains:

```
  <GridView
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  Width="1800"
  SelectionMode="None"
  IsSwipeEnabled="True"
  IsItemClickEnabled="False">
```

What must be added to make the gridview swipe normally, as in it won't bounce back to start once you let go of the screen?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to wrap your gridview with a scrollviewer?

```
<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}">
   <GridView ... />
</ScrollViewer>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR209527) is the msdn doc

Comment: Wasn't harder than that, now was it... That is great. Thank you.